# SPA Get Data per User

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, durandal, hottowel

I have built a SPA application with Hot Towel (durandal) and I have problems to understand the authentication.

When I am loading data from my database how can I filter this data to the current logged in userid ?

thanks for help,
Best Reguards

Comment: Show us what you already have!

Answer (score 0):

If your SPA is calling asp.net of any kind on the back end you can still use Forms Auth cookies to secure your ajax endpoints and identify the user making the request.  Depending on how SPA like you need it you can just use a standard aspx or mvc login page, then from there redirect the user to your SPA start page that calls your main.js and starts your SPA.  All ajax calls you make to that site will have the Forms Auth cookie set and you can use it to verify the user making the request.  Here is a link to [standard forms auth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xdt4thhy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  If you want handle the login process in durandal as well that can still be done, you just need to make your ajax endpoints for logging in and out to allow anonymous and then handle setting the forms auth cookie in them.

Answer (score 0):

On the server-side, referencing `User.Identity` in the controller will get you the properties of the currently authenticated user. The question is, what form of authentication does your application use (Windows, Forms, Basic, Anonymous, etc.)?